# R programming ranking a vector in a function

Tags: r, math

how do i build a function in R with a single vector that ranks the vector where and returns a n x n matrix where it returns 1 if i is preferred over j otherwise it returns 0.
I so far have this..

```
preferences <- matrix(nrow = n,ncol = n)

convert <- function(n){
for (i in 1:length(n)){
  for (j in 1:length(n)){

## If ith element < jth element then TRUE
 if (preferences[i,j] <- preferences[i] < preferences[j]){
  1
   }else if (preferences[i]==preferences[j]){
  0 
   } else{
  0}
}
}
print(preferences[i,j])
}
convert(c(8,1,3))
```

Comment: Please provide a small [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example along with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with `outer`

```
 +(outer(v1, v1, FUN= '<'))
```

---

If we need to create the diagonal elements, one option is

```
m1 <- matrix(0, length(n), length(n))
m1[col(m1)==row(m1)] <- n
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    8    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(1:7, 10, replace=TRUE)
n <- c(8,1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `diag`

```
n=c(8,1,3) 
diag(n, length(n), length(n))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    8    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
vec <- c(8,1,3)
outer(vec, vec, function(x,y){ifelse(x==y, x, 0)})
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked really well however i have to include loops :(